# How to have tailwind work in root ./pages directory in a next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Steps I took: created a new next.js project with npx create-next-app, added typescript and tailwind.css. Then I created a ./pages directory in the root of the project and added a testcss.tsx file under pages.
Also, I added the following line in tailwind.config.js:

```
'./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'
```

because by default it only has a reference to src/pages.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:
https://github.com/matheusrotta7/test-tailwind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the global.css file inside your pages directory, since it contains the css import for the tailwind classes.

```css
/* inside your global.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I recommend you create a folder called `styles` inside your `src` directory so you can import it inside your app's directories root [layout.tsx](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required) file and the [_app.tsx](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-app) file in the pages directory like so:

```
import "styles/global.css";

// rest of your layout or _app file
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but I'm having a hard time understanding the routing because some documentation shows the ./pages approach whereas others like the one you showed have the app router approach, and when you create a new app with the most recent next.js it uses a different structure. Anyway, accepted and thank you for your time!

Comment: This is because the app directory is fundamentally different from the pages directory. It comes with new features and is compatible with react server components and streaming.